# How to pass options to plugins when using babel-cli

Tags: babeljs, babel-cli

Is it possible to declare plugin options in the babel-cli --plugins argument? I can't find any mention or examples in the documentation.

Specifically I'm trying to translate the following from a .bashrc file (as described [here](https://github.com/morlay/babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore)) into a babel-cli --plugins argument:

```
...
"plugins": [
[
   "babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore",
   {
      "extensions": [".css", ".sass", ".scss"]
   }
]]
...
```

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: You found a solution for this ?

Comment: Sadly I have not.